# Infopath quick publish

Tags: infopath, publishing

Is there a way to undo a quick publish from infopath to SharePoint?

I have modified an existing published SharePoint form and the form no longer appears usable.

Can a reset be done without loosing existing data from original form?

Comment: Welcome to [SharePoint S.E.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com)! As far as I'm aware, you can't roll back without some sort of backup. For now, I'd advise trying to modify the form as best you can to make it usable again and do another publish. In the future, I'd suggest saving the previous form to your computer as a backup in case the changes you make invalidate the form in some way. You can **create another question** that has sufficient detail on what you're doing and the error(s) you receive and we may be able to fast track your form's recovery.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am clearly a novice. I will check if there is a back up available.

Comment: Typically you'll want to save the template to your computer or to some fileshare you might have in your company when you go to modify the infopath template, twice. The first will be your backup, the second will be the form you're going to modify and publish.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible. You should treat your InfoPath templates as source code and check in changes to a source control system. You should also at least have one other farm for testing.

In case something breaks, and it will, you can revert back to last version.